# Apache POI autoColumnWidth java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, out-of-memory, apache-poi

Am getting the `OutOfMemoryError` when the `autoColumnWidth` function is called on all the columns in my excel containing 1,28,237 rows and 20 columns. Am using `SXSSF` api and allocating `-Xms2048m -Xmx4096m -XX:PermSize=1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m` to JVM but still no success.
CPU utilization goes upto 100% , my system RAM is 6gb which is used upto 5.8gb during the process and then i get `OutOfMemoryError`. Any solution to it ?

With this, I can think of one solution i.e. taking a variable for each column, finding the max length and in the end after all data is entered set the column to respective variable.

Any other solution?

My Code To Create Excel

```
public static void createVideodataExcelFile(String excelPath, int maxRiskArea){

    FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

    CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
    XSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
    font.setColor(HSSFColor.BLACK.index);
    font.setBold(true);
    style.setFont(font);
    int cellCount = 0;

    try {
        File file = new File(excelPath);

        if(file.createNewFile()){
            SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(workbook); 
            wb.setCompressTempFiles(true);
            Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("GLE Video Data");
            int rowCount = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
            //System.out.println("Row Count ="+rowCount);
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rowCount);

            Cell cell1 = row.createCell(cellCount);
            createCell(cell1, row, "CourseContent name", style, cellCount);
            createCell(cell1, row, "lang", style, ++cellCount);
            createCell(cell1, row, "CourseTitle", style, ++cellCount);
            createCell(cell1, row, "Audience", style, ++cellCount);
            createCell(cell1, row, "ContentRegion", style, ++cellCount);
            createCell(cell1, row, "CourseTitle", style, ++cellCount);
            createCell(cell1, row, "DeprecatedId", style, ++cellCount);
            createCell(cell1, row, "GleCode", style, ++cellCount);
            createCell(cell1, row, "Guid", style, ++cellCount);
            createCell(cell1, row, "LearningFormat", style, ++cellCount);

            for(int i = 0 ; i < maxRiskArea ; ++i){
                createCell(cell1, row, "RiskArea", style, ++cellCount);
            }

            createCell(cell1, row, "SalesforceId", style, ++cellCount);
            createCell(cell1, row, "Setting", style, ++cellCount);
            createCell(cell1, row, "SmsCode", style, ++cellCount);
            createCell(cell1, row, "pageID", style, ++cellCount);
            createCell(cell1, row, "title", style, ++cellCount);
            createCell(cell1, row, "ID", style, ++cellCount);
            createCell(cell1, row, "media_src", style, ++cellCount);
            createCell(cell1, row, "cuePoint", style, ++cellCount);
            createCell(cell1, row, "character", style, ++cellCount);
            createCell(cell1, row, "line", style, ++cellCount);

            fileOut = new FileOutputStream(excelPath);
            wb.write(fileOut);
            System.out.println("Excel Of GLE Data Created.");
        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        errorLog.error("Excel Read/Write Error ="+e.getMessage());
        throw new GLEException(e);
    }
    finally{
        try {
            if(fileOut!=null)
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            errorLog.error("Excel Read/Write Error ="+e.getMessage());
            throw new GLEException(e);      

        }
    }
}

private static void createCell(Cell cell , Row row, String name, CellStyle style, int cellCount ){
    cell = row.createCell(cellCount);
    cell.setCellStyle(style);
    cell.setCellValue(name);
}
```

Comment: What paging size did you specify with SXSSF? The bigger the page, the more memory needed, but also the more accurate the sizing will be...

Comment: must be default, i haven't set the paging size

Comment: Can you post the few lines where you create the SXSSFWorkbook?

Comment: Why are you creating the SXSSFWorkbook from an empty XSSFWorkbook? For a new file, just create one directly, quite possibly setting a small-ish window size

Answer (score 0):

Try to call trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing() on the SXSSFSheet object before calling autoSizeColumn(columnIndex) and it will be fixed